# Creating a filtered list by comparing one list to another other list - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list and I need to get certain elements out of it. The way I did it was to compare the second list to the first list and then append to a third list. Here is my code:

```
l1 = ["0 = 0","1 = 1","2 = 2", "And", 
      "Something", "Wicked", "This", "Way", "Comes",
      f"zero.0 = 0", f"one.0 = 1", f"two.0 = 2",
      f"zero.1 = 0", f"one.1 = 1", f"two.1 = 2",
      f"zero.2 = 0", f"one.2 = 1", f"two.2 = 2",
      "purple", "monkey", "dishwasher"]
l3 = []
for element in l1:
   for i in range(3):
       l2 = [f"zero.{i} = 0", f"one.{i} = 1", f"two.{i} = 2"]
       for j in l2:
           if j in element:
               l3.append(element)
```

The results of this nested `for` loop is:

```
['zero.0 = 0', 'one.0 = 1', 'two.0 = 2', 'zero.1 = 0', 'one.1 = 1', 'two.1 = 2', 'zero.2 = 0', 'one.2 = 1', 'two.2 = 2']
```

The result is exactly what I want but I'm looking for a more Pythonic way of writing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is `i` defined in the second list?

Comment: I defined `i` in the `for` loop `for i in range(3):`

Comment: Ah, before your edit you had `l2` outside of your loop.

Comment: @Linny Yeah, I figured an edit would clear it up a bit. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Unnecessary format strings

Unless you intend to format a string right then and there, you don't need an `f` before it.

## Regex

This can be reduced to one line using regex:

```
import re

l3 = [item for item in l1 if re.match(r"\w{3,5}[.]\d\s[=]\s\d{1,}", item)]
```

## Explanation

- \w{3,5} matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

  - {3,5} Quantifier — Matches between 3 and 5 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- Match a single character present in the list below [.]

  - . matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
  - \d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
  - \s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
- Match a single character present in the list below [=]

  - = matches the character = literally (case sensitive)
  - \s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
- \d{1,} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

  - {1,} Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Comment: Very nice @Linny. I wanted to use `l3 = [x for x in l1 if any(y in x for y in l2)]` originally, but that only yielded `['zero.2 = 0', 'one.2 = 1', 'two.2 = 2']` for `l3`.